# Copy Multiple Ranges and Paste onto other worksheet next empty row?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy multiple ranges when a user clicks on a cell. I then want to paste these values onto another worksheet on the next available row.

Here's what i've tried so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$AB$12:$AD$13" Then
        Range("B1").Copy
        Range("E11").Copy
        Sheets("Data").Range("B" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
End Sub
```

But I get an application undefined error.

Comment: You have not defined nor set lastrow, vba will therefor not know the value of lastrow and throw an error

Comment: *'clicks a cell'* is not the same as selecting 6 specific cells. Your narrative says the former' your code the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am always a little leary when someone wants to trigger an event on nothing more that a change in cell selection but try this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AB12:AD13")) Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 2) = _
            Array(Range("B1").Value, Range("E11").Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

You might also want to look into the [Worksheet.BeforeDoubleClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.beforedoubleclick.aspx) event as an alternate way of triggering a transfer of values.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    lastrow = Worksheets("data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AB12:AD13")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("B1").Copy Sheets("Data").Range("B" & lastrow)
        Range("E11").Copy Sheets("Data").Range("C" & lastrow)
    End If
End Sub
```